# F# Close tcp client connection

Tags: f#

I have a simple tcp server that clients connect to and send message, after they send message I expect ack, well in normal conditions it works fine.

But for example If i will not receive ack message but something else I want to disconnect TcpCient from server, and here lies the problem, here what i have for disconnect function:

```
let DisconnectClient (client:TcpClient) (projectId:Option<uint32>) =
async {
    let disposeConnection (client:TcpClient) = 
        try
            let stream = client.GetStream().Close           
            let close = client.Close
            let dispose = client.Dispose
            _logger.Debug (sprintf "Client status %b, stream closed %A client closed %A, client disposed %A" (client.IsConnectionEstablished()) stream close dispose)

        with | :? ServerListenerException as ex -> _logger.Error(sprintf "Error while disconnecting client %s" ex.Message)

    match client, projectId with
    | null, _ -> async { return 0 } |> Async.StartAsTask |> ignore
    | _, Some id ->
        _logger.Info(sprintf "Disconnecting client %O with project id: %i" client.Client.RemoteEndPoint id)
        informationPools.RemoveFromConnectionPool id 
        disposeConnection client
    | _, None ->
        _logger.Info(sprintf "Batch disconnecting clients %O" client.Client.RemoteEndPoint)
        informationPools.RemoveFromConnectionPool client 
        disposeConnection client
}
```

And it called simply:

```
DisconnectClient client (Some data.ProjectId) |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

But when this procedure is completed client is still connected when I check by client.IsConnectionEstablished()

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a let binding for the function "Close".
Instead you want to call the close-function:

```
let close = client.Close // assign the function client.Close
client.Close() // actually execute the function
```

So you are actually assigning those three functions below, but never call them.

```
let stream = client.GetStream().Close           
let close = client.Close
let dispose = client.Dispose
```

You are therefore acutally looking for something like this:

```
client.GetStream().Close()
client.Close()
client.Dispose()
```

Comment: Damn simple mistake, I am ashamed and thank you for noticing